# WinAPI replacement for reg.exe

Tags: .net, windows, windows-7, windows-vista, registry

Are there WinAPI functions that do the same what can do standard Windows utility `reg.exe` with import/export flags?

I'm know that there are `RegSaveKey` and `RegRestoreKey` functions, but the calling process must have additional privileges `SE_RESTORE_NAME` and `SE_BACKUP_NAME`. This means that it is necessary to ask user to elevate process (show UAC dialog).

Seems to be that `reg.exe` does not require such privileges for HKCU keys. But starting `reg.exe` with some arguments is not good idea if there are appropriate WinAPI.

UPD: Brief reverse engineering has shown that `reg.exe` use internal parse functions.
Still may be are there .NET functions that does not require additional privileges?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there is not.  The RegSaveKey/RegRestoreKey functions also use a binary format, not the text format used by reg.exe.